# Из кортежа в строку

Tags: python

нужна помощь. Как из данной записи
`(378910822988120074,)` получить только 378910822988120074?

Код:

````
@bot.event
async def on_message(inter):
    channel = bot.get_channel(1000009793349619805)
    userid = inter.author.id
    with sqlite3.connect('glory.db') as db:
        c = db.cursor()
        exec = c.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = '{userid}'")
        id = int.join(exec.fetchone())
        update = c.execute(f"UPDATE users SET messages = messages + 1 WHERE id = '{exec}'")
        db.commit()
        print(id)
    db.close()
    ```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что такое `int.join`?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, полагаю, кортеж получается из чего-то типа `c.execute` в этом коде.

Comment: К вопросам выше. У меня есть база данных, в которой хранятся столбцы name, id, on_join и messages. Я получаю кортеж благодаря переменной `exec`:
exec = c.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = '{userid}'")

Он мне возвращает кортеж, который мне не нужен. Мне нужно его преобразовать в обычную строку.
`

Comment: @andreymal int join это ошибочка

Answer (score 1):

Отвечая на вопрос: `(378910822988120074,)` - кортеж.
Тогда и действуйте с ним, как с кортежем - обращайтесь к нужному элементу.
Например:

```
a = (378910822988120074,)
b = a[0]
c = str(a[0])
# Печатает: 378910822988120074 <class 'int'> 378910822988120074 <class 'str'> 
print (b, type(b), c, type(c))
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)